# Strange behavior of RandomAccessFile object

Tags: java

Here is a snippet of code that is behaving strangely.

```
    private void saveToFile() throws IOException {
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    File name = null;

        int returnVal = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(fileChooser);
    
    //Sets the variable name to the file the user selected.
    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
             name = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        //Exits the method if the user selected cancel in the dialog box.
    }else if (returnVal == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION) {
             return;
        }
    
    //Writes the text data to a file.
    try {
        //Writes the text in the textArea to the file which was selected.
        RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(name, "rw");
        raf.writeBytes(textArea.getText());
        raf.close();
    //Display the stack trace and an error message if the file could not be written.
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.print("    Cannot process file....\n");
    }
    
        //Displays the filename of which the file was saved to.
    String fileName = name.getName();
        super.setTitle("XText: " + fileName);
    
    //The text has now been saved and is no longer considered changed.
    changed = false;
}
```

The problem this code causes is when I save a file that was changed, back to itself and when the size is smaller that when it was when it was opened, the text saved is not the same as the text shown. I will show you all 3 text examples.

Opened file text.

Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.
Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.
Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back.
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back.
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back.

Changed to.

Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.
Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back.
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back.

Text in the saved file. Opened in another editor.

Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.
Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back.
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back.

lazy dogs back.
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back.
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back.

The text saves fine if it is saved to a new file.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you expect it to be truncated for you? You open existing file (e.g. size 1000) for writing, write (e.g) 800 bytes there -- the size is still 1000, just last 200 now contain garbage!

Try file.setLength(0) right after opening if you want to stick with random access file.

Otherwise, I'd suggest to:

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(name);
fw.write(text);
fw.close();
```

Comment: Great. That was sort of the answer I hoped I would get. My instructor had found the file.setLength(0) solution after I posted my problem. I will remember to use file.setLength(0) if I use RandomAccessFile object in the future. I wonder why the API for this object said nothing about having to do that, or am I just blind in one eye and can't see out of the other. Thanks for your help.

Comment: API comments doesn't say so because they assume you use RandomAccessFile for a reason. Because normally it's not the first choice for writing out a file.